# Conversão de valores

Tags: c#

Preciso que a string "hql" que seria meu select converta para int para eu poder assim fazer a comparação de valores em um if.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BlogWeb.ViewsModels;
using BlogWeb.DAO;
using BlogWeb.Models;
using BlogWeb.Filters;
using BlogWeb.Controllers;
using NHibernate;
using BlogWeb.Infra;

namespace BlogWeb.Controllers
    {
    public class GerenciamentoKM
        {
        private Rota p;
        private ISession session;
        public GerenciamentoKM(ISession session, Rota p, RotaDAO dao)
            {
            this.p = p;
            this.session = session;
            }
        public void soma(Rota post)
            {
            string hql = "SELECT p.Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE p.Km_Atual as LAST_INSERT_ID(Km_Atual)";
            int km_t = Convert.ToInt16(hql);
            if (km_t <= p.Km_Atual)
                {
                    ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
                    session.Update(post);
                    tx.Commit();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Esse não funciona, eu tentei depois executando a query antes

```
public void soma(Rota post)
        {
        string hql = "SELECT p.Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE p.Km_Atual as LAST_INSERT_ID(Km_Atual)";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
         query.List<Rota>();
        int km_t = Convert.ToInt16(hql);
        if (km_t <= p.Km_Atual)
            {
                ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
                session.Update(post);
                tx.Commit();
                }


        }
```

Desse jeito tambem não deu certo, ai tambem tentei iniciar ela por fora e puxar para a public.

```
public IList<Rota> Lista()
        {
        string hql = "SELECT p.Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE p.Km_Atual as LAST_INSERT_ID(Km_Atual)";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Rota>();
        }
public void soma(Rota post)
        {
        string hql = "SELECT p.Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE p.Km_Atual as LAST_INSERT_ID(Km_Atual)";
        if (Lista <= p.Km_Atual)
            {
                ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
                session.Update(post);
                tx.Commit();
                }


        }
```

Comment: Você não teria que executar a query primeiro? E depois converter o resultado?

Comment: Tentei executar com a query mas mesmo assim, ele não converte para integer.

Comment: Você precisa executar a _query_ antes de tentar fazer algo. Seu código atual está tentando **converter a _string_ `"SELECT p.Km_Atual ..."`**. Entende?

Comment: Tentei executar a query antes de tentar converter os dados porem agora ele informa que faz parte de um grupo de métodos, e se eu tentar colocar  no mesmo public void, o void não deixara de usar o return da query.

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Não dá pra entender o que você tá falando. Por favor, tente ser mais claro. Dê mais detalhes, [edit] a pergunta pode ajudar.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para mostra oque tentei fazer para rodar esse codigo.

Comment: Quando tento dar a atualização para troca de informação, aparece esse erro:  System.FormatException não foi manipulada pelo código do usuário
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.

Comment: Sobre seus testes como alguns já falaram você deve executar a query primeiro para depois obter o resultado e converter.
Verifique as dicas desse link. http://gabsferreira.com/como-fazer-queries-no-nhibernate-criteria-queryover-linq-to-nhibernate-hql-e-sql/

Answer (score 2):

Tente desta maneira:

```
string hql = "SELECT p.Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE p.Km_Atual as LAST_INSERT_ID(Km_Atual)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(hql, conn); //conn é a string da conexão.
conn.Open();
km_t = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Tentei testar, o problema que a classe de conexão que seria o "Conn" não pode ser importada para classe e ela está com outro nome que seria a Web.config

Answer (score 0):

Use o parametro "top 1", dessa forma, sua instrução SQL irá retornar um único valor e não uma lista de valores:

```
        SELECT top 1 p.Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE p.Km_Atual as LAST_INSERT_ID(Km_Atual)
```